# With my PHP, I'm trying to check on page load if the user hit submit (to get there) or just loaded the page, but if they just loaded I get an error

Tags: php, html

I'm checking it with `if ($_POST["submit"])` but of course if they didn't, it's trying to access a variable that doesn't exist. However, I was using this check to see if it did exist in the first place, but PHP outputs the error for me.

Is that... okay? I'm not doing anything with it, I'm just checking if it's there. Or is there a better way to do it?

Same thing with my radio buttons. If they hit submit I check to see their values, but if they hit submit without pressing any I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) for that:

```
if ( isset($_POST["submit"]) )
```

---

A better way would be to just check the [REQUEST_METHOD](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), to see if it's a POST request:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST' )
```

Comment: @DougSmith - Not as ambiguous. More reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check first your form method, be sure your code like this when dealing with `$_POST`;

```
<form method="post">
    ...
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="1">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="2">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

And then you can easily check your `$_POST` parameters by doing;

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "Form submitted!";
    // this makes gender and integer value or 0 silently
    @ $gender = (int) $_POST['gender'];
    if ($gender === 1) echo "Gender = 1";
    else if ($gender === 2) echo "Gender = 2";
    else echo "Gender = NULL";
    // and so on
```